# How to use ACTION_VIEW intent when loading image with Glide

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-glide

I know that I can use an ACTION_VIEW intent if I have the image saved physically on the device. But in my case I laod the images dynamically from an url, like this:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(mImageUrl)
            .into(mImageView);
```

Now I want to be able to open the image located at `mImageUrl` with the user's preferred gallery app when he clicks a button. How can I do that? Is it even possible or do I have to download and save the image?

Comment: what do you mean by "user's preferred gallery app"? do you want to pass Glide's downloaded image to another activity by using Intent? can you explain your aim?

Comment: I solved it and will update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
Basically Glide stores the downloaded image in the cache, and I couldn't get a download file path. So I did the following:

When the user clicks the "share" button I will download the image again (with glide) and save it in a .jpg file in the user's sdcard. Then I will use an ACTION_VIEW intent with the uri of the downloaded jpg.

Then the image stays saved in the user's gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso can be used to download the image.
 1. Use Picasso dependency inside gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'}
```

2. Use the following link for using inside activity or fragment

   [Picasso Link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Picasso does the same thing as Glide.