# "Media not found" when trying to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-glide, android-image

I'm using Glide library to load an image to an `ImageView`.
Since the image is stored in cache, I'm trying to access it via Glide and get the Uri of it to send via `Intent` to open another app to see the fullscreen image.

The way I'm loading the image to the `imageView`:

```kotlin
val url = GlideUrl(
              BASE_URL + "/api/files/download/?id=${list[position].fileID}",
              LazyHeaders.Builder()
                   .addHeader(
                       "token",
                       SessionManager.getInstance(context)
                            ?.getSession()
                            ?.token!!
                   )
                   .build())

Glide
     .with(imageViewAttachment)
     .load(url)
     .apply(RequestOptions()
            .fitCenter()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
      )
      .into(imageViewAttachment)
```

The way trying to send Uri via `Intent`:

```kotlin
val file = Glide
             .with(context)
             .asFile()
             .load(url)
             .submit()
             .get()
val uri = FileProvider
                .getUriForFile(
                       context, 
                       context.applicationContext.packageName + ".fileprovider", 
                       file
                )
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*")
context.startActivity(intent)
```

This is the Logs from the moment that it loads the files from cache to the ImageView :

```
2021-05-24 19:04:43.310 24974-24974/com.machadolemos.situations D/Glide: Finished loading BitmapDrawable from DATA_DISK_CACHE for http://qa2.machadolemos.com:60600/api/files/download/?id=1 with size [-2147483648x-2147483648] in 85.683021 ms
2021-05-24 19:04:43.801 24974-24974/com.machadolemos.situations D/Glide: Finished loading BitmapDrawable from DATA_DISK_CACHE for http://qa2.machadolemos.com:60600/api/files/download/?id=5 with size [-2147483648x-2147483648] in 561.9556769999999 ms
2021-05-24 19:04:45.983 24974-25079/com.machadolemos.situations D/Glide: Finished loading File from DATA_DISK_CACHE for http://qa2.machadolemos.com:60600/api/files/download/?id=5 with size [-2147483648x-2147483648] in 5.795208 ms
2021-05-24 19:04:48.545 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 2df12b3, I07da2d9908
    Build Date                       : 10/04/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2021-05-24 19:04:48.545 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2021-05-24 19:04:48.548 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2021-05-24 19:04:48.552 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
2021-05-24 19:04:48.554 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-05-24 19:04:48.554 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-05-24 19:04:48.555 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-05-24 19:04:48.555 24974-25043/com.machadolemos.situations D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
```

[The result of the Intent after selecting app to open the image is this toast saying Media not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbIss.png)

Any help with this issue?

Comment: Have you used file.exists() before you called your FileProvider? And did you have a look at its absolute path?

Comment: I didn't. i'll test that and let you know. But I'm almost certain that the file exists.

Comment: file= /data/user/0/com.machadolemos.situations/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/ea98e9238eca3f23bc387c7943219e1d76ab97f2a13d783fed2564c287c6b31a.0

Comment: uri= content://com.machadolemos.situations.fileprovider/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/ea98e9238eca3f23bc387c7943219e1d76ab97f2a13d783fed2564c287c6b31a.0

Comment: Just did a debug and the file and the uri exist

Comment: Try different apps to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

My not tested opinion is that you are trying to access file right away, when it might not be loaded yet, so you should add a listener to your Glide call and create intent under onResourceReady callback

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(glideUrl)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(object : SimpleTarget<File>(){
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: File?, transition: Transition<in File>?) {
                    //handle resource and create intent
                }
            })
```

Comment: Tried this to no success. I did notice a new warning when opening with a diferent app. 'the app can't open this type of file'. So I took a look at the device manager in Android Studio and checked the location of the file. The cached files do exist, but they end in .0 so I'm guessing that because the extension is not .jpg or .png, it isn't recognized.

Comment: I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303755/15259160. The solution was to create a new file .jpg to use via Intent. My only concern with this is that everytime the user clicks on that image, it will create a new file, so it will end up with multiple copies of the same image.

Comment: my advice would be to download file without Glide but via retrofit or any other method, save file to cache , upon click check whether file already exists or not and download if it does not, thaan show it to user , please check this link regarding retrrofit https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server